# aws: API Gateway is not able to connect to EKS cluster running in private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am having a use case where I need to deploy the EKS cluster in private subnets and access it through API Gateway.

Currently, if I deploy the EKS cluster in public subnet and try to access it is working fine. However, it is not working when the EKS cluster is deployed into the private subnet.

1. Currently API gateway is configured with VPC link to access EKS cluster securely.
2. Network load balancer is configured to connect to the EKS cluster nodes.

Please let me know if there is anything that I am missing here.

Thanks,

Avinash

Comment: You have to provide all the details of your setup. VPC setup, security groups, NLB setup, vpc link setup, ....

Comment: Does your nodes allow traffic from NLB? Does your private subnet have NAT gateway?

Comment: @Ash I have created EKS cluster with the private subnet that is having the NAT gateway